# Multiple View Delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I currently have a project with multiple views handling data and I just need some clarifiation on best practice on handing data around.

For instance: `MainView` displays a table of info that is added via a modal `AddInfoView`.
The data is passed to `MainView` using delegation which works well. However within `AddInfoView` there is a `tableView` cell which allows the user to select from a list of options which is presented by a push segue to another view, lets call it `OptionsView`.

As I can see it I have two options which would work best.

Option A: The data gets passed down the stack - Objects get passed from `OptionsView` to `AddInfoView` which then passes it to `MainView` to be displayed. With each view down the chain being delegates.

OR

Option B: `MainView` is the delegate of both `AddInfoView` as well as `OptionsView` and the data gets passed directly to that view to be displayed.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd choose Option A if the `OptionsView` is displayed by the `AddInfosView` only. As it makes more sense, you push down the way to `OptionView`, so it should push up the way through AddInfosView as well.

I agree that if `AddInfosView` doesn't need any of the `OptionView` datas returned, it would be pretty useless to pass thourhg the `AddinfosView`, but to keep it consistant i'd still pass through as we did it to show the `OptionsView`.